# add-migration keeps insisting on seeding AspNetRoles

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF/Identity in my .net Core api project. I setup some seeding code like this...

```
public class RoleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityRole>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IdentityRole> builder)
    {
        builder.HasData(
            new IdentityRole
            {
                Name = "Administrator",
                NormalizedName = "ADMINISTRATOR"
            },
            new IdentityRole
            {
                Name = "Member",
                NormalizedName = "MEMBER"
            }
        );
    }
}
```

When I run add-migration it's consistently will try to delete/re-add these roles. The Up code is here...

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
            table: "AspNetRoles",
            keyColumn: "Id",
            keyValue: "744c5709-b679-4db6-97a8-1b73acfd4f9c");

        migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
            table: "AspNetRoles",
            keyColumn: "Id",
            keyValue: "86ae592b-f2f9-40bb-be56-446f58fdfe01");

        migrationBuilder.InsertData(
            table: "AspNetRoles",
            columns: new[] { "Id", "ConcurrencyStamp", "Name", "NormalizedName" },
            values: new object[] { "92f21e92-c63c-4c82-b4c9-a7482846ec50", "5dff2adb-ea6a-4d63-8b40-004660af85a8", "Administrator", "ADMINISTRATOR" });

        migrationBuilder.InsertData(
            table: "AspNetRoles",
            columns: new[] { "Id", "ConcurrencyStamp", "Name", "NormalizedName" },
            values: new object[] { "b3aacf73-79fa-4aac-9a8a-0ea78074aac8", "9722dda8-cd29-49b4-baf7-1249737a69bf", "Member", "MEMBER" });
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I only want this to run the first time, to seed the database.

Thanks!

Comment: IdentityRole and AspNetRoles are two different tables isn't it?

Comment: @NickB only AspNetRoles is in the db.